# Calling h2o.group_by with dynamic arguments

Tags: r, h2o, do.call

I have a question regarding the use of do.call() on H2O's group_by() function.

Consider the following example:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# Import the airlines data set and display a summary.
airlinesURL <- "https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-airlines-unpacked/allyears2k.csv"
airlines.hex <- h2o.importFile(path = airlinesURL, 
destination_frame = "airlines.hex")


h2o.group_by(data = airlines.hex, 
             by="Origin",
             nrow("Origin"), 
             min("Origin"), 
             max("Origin"), 
             gb.control=list(na.methods="rm"))
```

The output is shown below:

```
  Origin nrow min_Origin max_Origin
1    ABE   59          0          0
2    ABQ  876          1          1
3    ACY   31          2          2
4    ALB   75          3          3
5    AMA   11          4          4
6    ANC    1          5          5
```

Now, instead of the above direct call to h2o.group_by(), I would like to use a do.call() function to call h2o.group_by(). The reason is that I would like to dynamically build the list of fields to be summarized (i.e. nrow("Origin"), max("Origin") etc.).

So, I tried this (and many variations of the following code):

```
do.call(h2o.group_by, list(data=airlines.hex, 
                           by="Origin", 
                           nrow("Origin"), 
                           min("Origin"), 
                           max("Origin"), 
                           gb.control=list(na.methods="rm")), 
        quote=FALSE)
```

I get an error:

```
Error in if (ag == "sd") ag <- "\"sdev\"" : argument is of length zero
```

Does anyone know how to get the do.call() function to work in this case? Basically, I need to be able to call h2o.group_by() with a dynamically generated set of fields to be summarized.

In the worst case, I believe that I can use eval and parse to do what I need. In other words:

```
eval(parse(text="
h2o.group_by(data = airlines.hex, 
             by=\"Origin\",
           nrow(\"Origin\"), 
           min(\"Origin\"), 
           max(\"Origin\"), 
           gb.control=list(na.methods=\"rm\"))
           "))
```

I was wondering that do.call might be a better approach to use.

Any suggestions on how to get do.call to produce the intended result?

Karthik

Comment: `quote=TRUE` gives the same result?

Comment: If I use quote=TRUE instead of quote=FALSE, I get the following error: Error in agg[[2]] : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I think you are looking for something like the code below. Does this meet your needs?

```
airlinesGroupBy <- function(by)
{
  do.call(h2o.group_by,
          list(data = airlines.hex, 
               by = by, 
               call("nrow", by), 
               call("min", by), 
               call("max", by), 
               gb.control = list(na.methods = "rm")))
}
airlinesGroupBy("Origin")
```

Comment: This absolutely meets my needs! I had never explicitly used the call() function before. Thanks.